# Should I increase sort_buffer_size in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am running a site which extensively queries a MySQL DB. Some pages querying the DB server loads very slowly and I am pretty sure it is due to the DB server. Just by looking into the DB server usage, I can see that the iowait is >10 seconds, the swap space is also partially used. After turning on the slow-query-log, I found one query is consistently slow. The query looks like

```
select g.citing from g, c where g.cited=8992 and g.citing=c.id order by c.size desc limit 20;
```

Typical query time is about 10 seconds. The innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 24GB. I read some MySQL manual pages, and found that I may need to tune the sort_buffer_size parameter because the `Sort_merge_passes` status variable is very high (about 310818). The current value of `sort_buffer_size` is 2M and I am not sure if I should go up or down because some people said never go beyond 2M. 
The current query does not take advantage of index. The result of the "EXPLAIN" statement gives the following results:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g         | ref    | citing,cited  | cited   | 8       | const                          |  306 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id    | PRIMARY | 8       | db1.g.citing                    |    1 |                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

I tried to consider a better query, which can take advantage of index, but no luck for now. Can anyone help me out? I appreciate it.

Comment: The very first thing you want to do is to make an explicit join between your table. Learn about joins http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: What is your hardware. How big your tables are?

Comment: You should consider adding an index on `size.`

Comment: there's a special index for "size" already, but this does not help because according to MySQL manual, in our case, MySQL does not use index to do "SORT BY"

Comment: The c table is over 30 million rows. There are 8 cores 32gb of memory and 1.5 tv of disk space. The db server is in a private cloud.

Comment: May I ask what's the advantage of using an explicit join?

Comment: @fanchyna this might be a gross over-simplification, but to give you an idea - with the join you're using, MySQL is querying every row in `c` *for every row in `g`*. You say there are 30 million rows in `c`. If there are 1,000 rows in `g` then you're asking MySQL to query 30 billion rows. With explicit joins, the above query runs much more efficiently (I think it would be `g` + `c` instead of `g` * `c` rows, but don't quote me on that).

Answer (score 1):

### In short, no.

Not if you can avoid it.

Before increasing memory allocation of any kind, try and look for an alternative solution. Usually this would be one (or both) of two things: query optimisation and indexing.

In your case, the query can be optimised quite significantly. What it's currently doing is querying every row in `g` *multiplied by* every row in `c`, then applying the `where` clause, then the `order by`, then the `limit`.

If you use a join instead, like so:

```
select g.citing from g
inner join c on g.citing=c.id
where g.cited=8992
order by c.size desc
limit 20;
```

What this does is to query every row in `g`, then query every row in `c` to find matches, then it applies the `where` clause on the intersection of the two tables - far fewer rows than before - followed by the `order by` and the `limit`.

With a primary index on c.id and indexes on g.citing and g.cited you should increase the speed and decrease the memory usage a lot further too.